# how to add and subtract GB and MB in excel sheets

Tags: excel, math

I have get reports everyday of application sizes and they come in either M for MB and G for GB.  I get about 100 of them at 9:00 and they need to be out by 9:30 so is there any way that you can make a formula to subtract a cell with 128M from a cell with 100M or 2.2G?

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is not clearly worded. Include what your data is now, with a specific example, with a specific cell reference, and what you want your data to be. Please also indicate what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Yes, e.g. would you like your results always to be in Mb, always in Gb, or depend how big the answer is? Would you like them to have M or G on the end?

Answer (score 1):

If it always has a G or M at the end:-

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)*IF(RIGHT(A1)="G",1000,1)
```

applied to each of the two cells, then subtract.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"G",REPT("0",4-FIND(".",A1))),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"M","")),".","")
```

for removal of the `G`s and `M`s prior to subtraction.